# Weird issue with external constants in constructor of template classes

Tags: c++, static-order-fiasco

I have the following three source files:

main.cc:

```
#include "constants.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t n> class Foo {
    public:
    static const double bar;
    Foo();
};

template <std::size_t n> const double Foo<n>::bar = 4*pi;

template <std::size_t n> Foo<n>::Foo() { std::cout << "ctor: " << bar << std::endl; }

const Foo<42> baz;

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "main(): " << Foo<42>::bar << std::endl;
    std::cout << "main(): " << baz.bar << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

constants.cc:

```
#include "constants.h"

const double pi = 3.1415;
```

constants.h:

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

extern const double pi;

#endif
```

and when I compile and link everything and run the executable I get:

```
ctor: 0
main(): 12.566
main(): 12.566
```

What gives?  How comes the constructor of Foo<42> can't see the correct value of pi?  This seems to only happen if Foo is a template, and only if pi is defined in a different file.

For what it's worth I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0.  All of `--std={c++,gnu++}{98,03,11,14,17}` give the same results.

TIA for your answers.

Comment: static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: Fix it by making `pi` a `constexpr`? Or use boost pi instead (to avoid the fiasco).

Comment: Also see [these mathematical constants available in the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants)

Comment: I think you have encountered "unordered dynamic initialization" (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)). There is a surprising (at least to me) special case (i.e. a bug waiting to happen) for initialization of "class template static data members [...] that aren't explicitly specialized".

Comment: If you can use c++20 [constinit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit) will solve this easily.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher `constexpr` works, but prior to C++17 it was required to have internal linkage and I'd rather not duplicate objects. I went for `#if __cplusplus > 201700L
inline constexpr double constant = VALUE;
#else
#define constant (VALUE)
#endif`